# How to avoid AssertionError while executing a query over Hive table in ORC format from pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, orc

I am running a simple Hive query from PySpark but it throws an error. The table is in ORC format. Need some help in it. Below is the code

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Termination_Calls Snapshot").config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true").config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
x_df = spark.sql("SELECT count(*) as RC from bi_schema.table_a")
```

This throws error like below

> ```
> Hive Session ID = a00fe842-7099-4130-ada2-ee4ae75764be 
> Traceback (mostrecent call last):   
> File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   
> File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 716, in sql
> return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)   
> File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",line 1257, in __call__   
> File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63,
> in deco return f(*a, **kw)   
> File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o70.sql. : java.lang.AssertionError: assertion
> failed at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:156) at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveMetastoreCatalog.convertToLogicalRelation(HiveMetastoreCatalog.scala:214)
> ```

When I run the same query in hive I get the result as expected and its shown below.

```
+-------------+
|     rc      |
+-------------+
| 3037579538  |
+-------------+
1 row selected (25.469 seconds)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Bug in Spark, specific to ORC format.

setting below property in sparkContext configuration will resolve issue:

`spark.conf.set("spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc", "false")`

If we take close look into spark code for [HiveMetastoreCatalog](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.2/sql/hive/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveMetastoreCatalog.scala) then seems like

`assert(result.output.length == relation.output.length &&
      result.output.zip(relation.output).forall { case (a1, a2) => a1.dataType == a2.dataType })` 
is failing. This means it is checking the number of columns and datatypes. One reason can be that after alter table metastore is not updated but that is very unlikely.

Then i thought of creating JIRA ticket for same but turns out that ORC format always had some issues. There is already two JIRA tickets for regarding this issue:

1. [SPARK-28098](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-28098)
2. [SPARK-28099](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-28099)

If we keep `spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc` to default `true` then it will use the vectorized reader [official doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/sql-programming-guide.html#orc-files). Because of this bug the number of columns are mismatching and assertion is failing. I am suspecting that this property is resulting in some dummy columns are added while using vectorized reader.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try the below steps once , because i think we cannot query the hive table directly using HiveContext

```
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
hive_context = HiveContext(sc)
result= hive_context.table("bi_schema.table_a")
```

And after fetching the table in the above manner, we need to register that result dataframe as temptable like below

```
result.registerTempTable("table_a")
```

Now we can query select statement on that table as below

```
x_df = hive_context.sql("SELECT count(*) as RC fromtable_a")
```

Comment: I cannot register my table each time, as I have 100's of tables coming dynamically. Instead of sparkcontext i am using spark session. Thats the only difference from my answer and yours