# py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o69.sql. java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, jupyter-notebook

While running a simple Spark SQL

```
spark.sql("select count(1) from edw.result_base").show()
```

...I'm getting this error

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o69.sql. java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
```

The table is in **parquet** format, and Spark version is **2.4.8**.

I tried setting the below property and still got an error.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc", "true")
```

The complete stacktrace for the error look like this:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
      at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:208)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveMetastoreCatalog.convertToLogicalRelation(HiveMetastoreCatalog.scala:261)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveMetastoreCatalog.convert(HiveMetastoreCatalog.scala:137)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.RelationConversions$$anonfun$apply$4.applyOrElse(HiveStrategies.scala:220)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.RelationConversions$$anonfun$apply$4.applyOrElse(HiveStrategies.scala:207)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDown$2(AnalysisHelper.scala:108)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:72)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDown$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:108)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:194)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:106)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:104)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDown$4(AnalysisHelper.scala:113)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:376)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:214)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:374)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:327)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDown$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:113)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:194)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:106)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:104)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperators(AnalysisHelper.scala:73)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperators$(AnalysisHelper.scala:72)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.RelationConversions.apply(HiveStrategies.scala:207)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.RelationConversions.apply(HiveStrategies.scala:191)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$2(RuleExecutor.scala:130)
      at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foldLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:60)
      at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:68)
      at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foldLeft(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1(RuleExecutor.scala:127)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1$adapted(RuleExecutor.scala:119)
      at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:119)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$$executeSameContext(Analyzer.scala:168)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:162)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:122)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$executeAndTrack$1(RuleExecutor.scala:98)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:88)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.executeAndTrack(RuleExecutor.scala:98)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1(Analyzer.scala:146)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:201)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:145)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$analyzed$1(QueryExecution.scala:66)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:111)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:63)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:63)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)
```

Comment: Hi! We're missing the interesting part of your error. Can you share what the full error message is (including the Java error stack trace if there is one) by editing your question? Also, is `edw.result_base` a view? A table?

Comment: @Koedlt . Its an external table and we have some internal managed tables getting same error.

Comment: @Koedlt I have added detailed error. Any suggestion pls

Comment: Ahh damn I also forgot to ask you: what is your spark version?

Answer (score 0):

After having looked around a bit, it seems like you're on the right path by looking at that `spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc` parameter (see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57695564/15405732) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40388322/15405732) for similar errors). Since you're using parquet as underlying storage though, it will be the `spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet` parameter that you will need.

Try setting `spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet` to `false` instead of `true`. `true` is the [default value](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ce5ddad990373636e94071e7cef2f31021add07b/sql/hive/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveUtils.scala#L139-L144), so that won't get you very far since the default behaviour is what's giving you this error.

Comment: @Koedit. I tried with "false" as well and getting the same error. Any other way I can try

Comment: @Koedit. I tried and getting error as :::::::  py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o285.showString  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: parquet/hadoop/ParquetOutputFormat

Comment: It seems like you don't have the necessary `parquet-hadoop` jar. This is fixable but maybe it's easier to reinstall spark. How did you install Spark?

Comment: @Koedit I tried updating to read specific jar "parquet-hadoop-bundle-1.6.0.jar" but its not able to read in the spark.session builder. Any suggestion pls

Comment: when i run the spark-submit command by explicitly specifying the --driver-class-path I am able to get the count but when I use "pyspark" shell manually and tried all the ways to read this --driver-class-path inside spark session its not able to read it. Any suggestion if possible here

Comment: Ok so you can start up your `pyspark` shell with that configuration by doing so: `pyspark --driver-class-path YOUR_CLASS_PATH`. This should start up your pyspark shell with the same configuration as your spark-submit command.

Comment: Its still not adding this jar file to the session. Unable to define in any way to pyspark shell

Answer (score 0):

This assertion error indicates that logical schema of your Hive table `edw.result_base` doesn't match physical schema of the underlying parquet files. Here is the relevant code in [`HiveMetastoreCatalog.scala`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/sql/hive/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveMetastoreCatalog.scala#L255):

> ```
> :
> // The inferred schema may have different field names as the table schema, we should respect
> // it, but also respect the exprId in table relation output.
> assert(result.output.length == relation.output.length &&
>   result.output.zip(relation.output).forall { case (a1, a2) => a1.dataType == a2.dataType })
> :
> ```

You can certainly simply disable `spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet`, but I think a safer approach would be to figure out where the differences are because otherwise they may lead to incorrect query results (especially if data types don't match or you have extra columns in your table def).

Please also note that in the newer Spark versions this `assert` was refactored to throw more detailed and accurate `AnalysisException`s.

For setting driver classpath in Jupyter, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51772350/how-to-specify-driver-class-path-when-using-pyspark-within-a-jupyter-notebook) seems to work, although I don't think any extra jars are needed in your case since you're able to infer schema from parquet just fine.